# Soma em php não funciona

Tags: php, html, soma

Bom dia, estou com o seguinte problema: Quero somar a avaliação inicial com a avaliação final e o resultado aparecer na tela mas aparece sempre zero, onde estou a falhar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="AvInicial" type="text" class="validate"
               autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial">
        <label for="avinicial"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="Meta" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
               name="Meta">
        <label for="meta"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="AvIntercalar" type="text" class="validate"
               autocomplete="off" name="AvIntercalar">
        <label for="avintercalar"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="AvFinal" type="text" class="validate" autocomplete="off"
               name="AvFinal">
        <label for="avfinal"></label>
    </div>
</th>
<th>
    <div class="input-field col s12">
        <?
            $a = $_GET['avinicial'];
            $b = $_GET['avfinal'];
              echo $a + $b;
        ?>
    </div>
</th>
```

Comment: faz um var_dump das variaveis $a e $b para garantir que ambas estão populadas e sao inteiros

Comment: Da um echo separadamente nas variáveis para ver se os valores estão chegando.

Comment: @DiegoVieira Fiz tal como disse e realmente os valores não estão chegando.

Comment: Você está enviando esses dados por GET mesmo? Não seria via POST?

Comment: @KayoBruno tentei com POST e nada deu, em pesquisa vi que deve ser com GET

Comment: Amigo faça o seguinte: echo '<pre>'; print_r( $_GET ); die;
Isso vai mostrar todos os valores dentro de $_GET, e mostra pra gente o que "printou".

Comment: @KayoBruno ficou a pensar e não aparece nada. Ta sempre a pensar e nem o resto da tabela mostra.

Comment: da um intval($a) + intval($b)

Comment: verifica se sua div não está com display:none

Comment: Creio que está dando erro, porém seu php pode estar configurado para não mostrar. tente substituir as seguintes linhas por. $a = isset($_GET['avinicial'])?$_GET['avinicial']:0; $b = isset($_GET['avfinal'])?$_GET['avfinal']:0;

Comment: @MarcosBrinner nada mudou, muito obrigado pela ajuda na mesma!

Comment: adicione essas linhas  no  inicio  do seu codigo para ver se exibe algum erro

Comment: ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Você está mesmo enviando esses valores via $_GET? Posta seu código html. completo assim podemos ajudar.

Comment: Cara os nomes dos campos estão diferentes dos nomes que você tá tentando pegar via GET:
AvInicial != avinicial

Comment: @KayoBruno eu não preciso da AvIntercalar para esta soma é só a AvInicial e AvFinal

Comment: @DavidVinicius                                                                       
   $nrutente = $_POST['NrUtente'];
    echo $nrutente;

    $avinicial = $_POST['AvInicial'];
    $meta = $_POST['Meta'];
    $avintercalar = $_POST['AvIntercalar'];
    $avfinal = $_POST['AvFinal'];
    $datainicio = $_POST['DataInicio'];
    $datafim = $_POST['DataFim'];

Comment: @VilelaVilela ai você está recebendo, o que eu acho que pode estar ocorrendo é que você não está fazendo o submit do form, pelo menos no código que mostrou não vi nenhum tipo de Action que faça o submit desse form.

Comment: @DiegoVieira então como aconselha a alterar o código de modo a colocar um submit?

Comment: primeira certifique-se que o código esteja entre as tags <form> ( seu código) </form>.  Você pode colocar <button type="submit">ENVIAR</button>. ao clicar nesse botão ele enviará seu form.

Comment: Cara além dos nomes dos campos estarem diferentes, você não deu um submit, apenas tá tentando somar valores que não foram setados.
Dá uma pesquisada em exemplos de formulários GET e POST em PHP. Isso vai te ajudar um pouco.

Comment: bom nesse caso você poderia apenas fazer a some em  javascript ao invez de php, seria bem  mais rapido

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um exemplo básico com 2 campos baseando-se no seu form, tenta usar como exemplo para fazer com os outros.

```
<form action="">
    <table>
         <th>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <input id="AvInicial" type="text" class="validate"
                    autocomplete="off" name="AvInicial">
                <label for="avinicial">campo 1</label>
            </div>
        </th>            
        <th>
            <div class="input-field col s12">

                <label for="avfinal"> campo 4</label>
                <input id="Avfinal" type="text" class="validate"
                    autocomplete="off" name="Avfinal">
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <?php
                $a = isset($_GET['AvInicial']) ? $_GET['AvInicial'] : 0;
                $b = isset($_GET['Avfinal']) ? $_GET['Avfinal'] : 0;
                echo $a + $b;
                ?>

            </div>
        </th>
        <th>
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </th>
```

Comment: tbm acho  q ele esquece das tags do form

Comment: O que está acontecer é que está a gravar a página toda esse botão.